# What does “quite a” (as in “He’s quite a guy”) mean, and when should one use it?

Tags: articles, expressions, sarcasm

What does the following sentence mean?

> He is **quite a guy**.

In which situation would *quite a* be used?

Comment: _Quite a_ is a determiner idiom phrase that means the same thing as _very_, except that _very_ can only modify adjective and adverb phrases, while _quite a_ can modify noun phrases. Including the idiom _quite a lot_, which also means _very much_, and can modify verb phrases.

Comment: @JohnLawler Now you’ve sent me haring off to try to decide what difference they might be between *quite the* and *quite a*.  Does the article’s definiteness matter?

Comment: @JohnLawler; so, quite a guy means quite a nice guy?

Comment: @Itsme You seem to have snuck a *nice* in there, which may or may not apply. It certainly isn’t automatic.

Comment: 'He's quite a guy' is in the same ballpark semantically as 'What a guy!' (though not quite as effusive).

Comment: @tchrist "Does the article’s definiteness matter?" definitely, same as it does elsewhere. Think over.

Comment: "I knew he would do that. He's quite **the** guy."

Comment: @itsme: "quite a guy" can be understood as "an impressive guy". He could be impressive for any number of reasons. Certainly he could be impressively nice, but he could also be impressively savvy, or impressively musical, or, if the phrase was being used sarcastically, impressively cruel or even, used ironically, unimpressive. But when not used sarcastically, the phrase usually does carry a positive tone, and often the connotation that the person in question is impressive for several reasons (or impressive in several different ways): a well-rounded kind of impressive.

Comment: note that "quite a guy" could mean "quite a player", ie, the "guy" could, possibly, be a negative sense.  (essentially, he's "quite an asshole" or "quite a sexist pig" sort of thing.)  or, by all means, it could me "he is a very good person".

Comment: _He's quite a guy_ would mean **He's very a guy* (if we could say that). Whatever guyhood means to the speaker, _he_ encapsulates it. This varies widely, of course, depending on the speaker and the addressee.

Comment: @Kris So for you saying that *someone is quite **the** fisherman* would have a different connotation than saying that *someone is quite **a** fisherman* would have?

Comment: Oh, and @tchrist: I grew up with _quite a_; _quite the_ strikes me as affected and hyperbolic.

Comment: tchrist - the question you have raised is a very good one. you rock. **here's my take** as best I can put it in words.  "quite the" means: "i believe there's a platonic, perhaps let's say almost comic or clichéd version, of, the thing in question; the discussion at hand gives us a chance to refer to that storyesque, perhaps humorous characterisation - and furthermore the person at hand comes close to being a real-life instantiation of that"; whereas "quite a" means "very".

Comment: John L - "affected and hyperbolic", it could be, but I'd say (in very simple terms) - it's humorous; it directs our attention to a cliché or trope, at the same time as commenting on the person at hand.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What words typically collocate with "quite"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23035/what-words-typically-collocate-with-quite)

Comment: @tchrist: To me, *"He's quite **a** comedian"* would be more likely in contexts where "he" is commonly acknowledged to be a comedian (as a "permanent" attribute, not necessarily having just done or said anything funny). But I'm more likely to use *"He's quite **the** comedian"* in contexts where he's just done/said something justifying the label *at that particular time* (very likely where in other contexts I wouldn't consider "acting the funny guy" to be something he typically does). So for me there *can* be a bit of a difference.

Comment: Yes, I believe that if the quality-object is just some measure .. he's quite a driver, he's quite a programmer, he's quite a cook, he's quite a painter, he's quite a writer ... than "quite a" works.  However, if the other phrase is, in itself, a comic trope, cliché, or humurously-ornate phrase, then quite-the works.  He's quite the girl's blouse, this is quite the rococo chandelier, he's quite the living legend, etc.

Answer (score 2):

According to [OOD](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/quite-a-%E2%80%94%E2%80%94-also-often-ironic-quite-the-%E2%80%94%E2%80%94?q=quite%20a):

> **quite a ...** (*also often IRONIC* **quite the ...**)
>
> Used to indicate that the specified person or thing is perceived as
> particularly notable, remarkable, or impressive. ⇒ *"quite a party, isn’t it?"*

According to [CED](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/quite-a#quite-a_1):

> **quite a ...**
>
> *(not used with a negative)* of an exceptional, considerable, or noticeable kind ⇒ *quite a girl, quite a long walk*

According to [LEDO](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/quite):

> **quite a something/quite some something**
>
> *British English* used before a noun to emphasize that something is very good, large, interesting ⇒ *The engines make quite a noise.*

---

But we all know that the word *quite* can also function as an adverb with the definition:

> to the utmost or most absolute extent or degree ⇒ *this is quite a different problem.*

or

> to a certain or fairly significant extent or degree; fairly ⇒ *he’s quite an attractive man.*

and therefore "**quite a ...**" can also be interpreted as:

> *a ... to the greatest extent*

or

> *a ... to some extent*.

It all depends on the context.

Answer (score 0):

> In which situation would *quite a* be used?

It would be used when you would look at the object in question, consider examples relating to someone or something exemplifying the attributes of that object, and consider that the person or thing exceedingly represents that object.

> That Ferrari is quite a car!
>   (A Ferrari isn't *just* a car, it is a car, plus plus plus).

That's the "straight" definition.

However, it's also used in some contexts to present the comparison where it wouldn't make sense, but applied in a way that might be sarcastic:

> That Charlie Brown Christmas tree is quite a tree, isn't it?

Here, the reversal is that the tree isn't much more than essentially a branch, so the usage is to slightly demean the appearance without outright saying, "That's an ugly tree!"

In general, it's probably not quite a term to be used unless you really want to call attention to the object as extremely indicative (or much better/worse) than the average of its type.

Answer (score -1):

Answer: *“quite a”* means *very*.

Comment: Applying this stated equivalence directly to the quoted question renders "a very guy". Applying it directly to "that was quite a meal!" renders "that was a very meal!". Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: "a very guy" guy or "a very meal" meal is clear to me.  (note carefully that it could indeed mean "bad or good" in each case.  you can very much say "that was quite the meal" if it was just too much, too filling, etc (for example).)

Comment: Whoever voted this down is silly.  it's a simple question - and it should have a simple answer.  **Note too that I am using the exact minimum number of characters that can be used in an answer** -- shocked that wasn't noticed.

Comment: Note that just because a word/phrase exactly means some other word - it's completely unsurprising that you are not able to simply substitute one for another, in the same sentence structure.  Note too that you can simply say "that was a meal" (often "now that was a meal") to mean pretty much exactly the same thing (again, good or bad). In these phrases the interesting part is **how you are using guy, or meal**  the "quite the" is nothing.  You're using "guy" or "meal" to mean "the epitome of Guyness" "epitome of mealness" (again - for better or worse).

Comment: Of course I know what you mean, but either this question is too simple to merit an answer, or it merits a helpful (and not confusing -- to *someone who doesn't already know what "quite a" means*) answer. I recommend we either port this over to ELL, or you include a dictionary definition, or something more substantial from the comments ("a determiner...", "understood as 'impressive'..."), etc. As it stands, this answer will not be helpful for the next person who comes along.

Comment: John Lawler has proved that you can't use *very* in all the situations that you can use "quite a" nor vice versa. This answer is insufficient.

Comment: Also, I'll note that while "a very meal" could be easily understood as "a very mealy meal" (=having a greater degree meal-like characteristics), and that works so far as it goes, it does not work for "a very guy-y guy", because having a greater-degree-of-guy-like-characteristics is basically saying a "a very masculine guy", which is too specific, and in the case of "quite a guy" usually off the mark. "Very" can't stand alone, *Heathers* notwithstanding :)

Comment: You're completely wrong, "a very guy guy" works exactly like "a very meal meal".  Of course it does.  (Of course, obviously, you and I could have different meanings, or at different times have different meanings, of a "guy" guy (either strong, mean - whatever)

Comment: Hi Matt --   I'll just cut and paste what I already typed.   Of course you (say!) could be "very guy" or a meal could be "very meal".  I also already typed "Note that just because a word/phrase exactly means some other word - it's completely unsurprising that you are not able to simply substitute one for another, in the same sentence structure. "

Comment: Hi Dan - if you wanna move it to ELL, do so.  I think you're crazy to ignore the fact that I **perfectly answered in the exact minimum number of characters!**  That's so beautiful man!

Comment: Hey, you're talking to a guy who gets a little thrill whenever he tweets something in *exactly* 140 characters. If there were a  button for poetic (or poetically laconic) responses, you can be sure  I'd push it. Sadly, there isn't.

Comment: I didn't get the answer :(

Comment: I have done some research on google

**quite a** is an adverb

It means
_of an unusually noticeable or exceptional or remarkable kind (not used with a negative); "her victory was quite something"; "she's quite a girl"; "quite a film"; "quite a walk"; "we've had quite an afternoon"_

Comment: it's common to use it with a negative.  example, we're exhausted after a walk "phew, that was quite a walk".